# The characteristic function of $X_t$ in a AR(1) process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, characteristic-functions, time-series

Let  $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}$ an ergodic and stationary $AR(1)$ process. That is, let $$X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$  where $(\epsilon_t)$ is an iid noise sequence. Can I say that the characteristic function of $X_t$ is the same for every $t$? That is:
$$\varphi_{X_{t_1}}= \varphi_{X_{t_2}}, \quad \forall t_1 \neq t_2 $$
Some help?

Comment: What definition of stationarity are you using?

Comment: weak stationarity! But the noise $\epsilon_t$ in the AR(1), $X_t =  \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, is an i.i.d white noise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the characteristic functions of $X_{t_1}$ and $X_{t_2}$ are the same; this follows because $X_t$ is in fact a **strongly** stationary process, so that all the marginal distributions are the same. This is a special case of the fact that [linear processes driven by strong white noise are strongly stationary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226667/is-an-mathrmarma1-1-process-with-an-mathrmarch1-innovation-strictl/4226731#4226731).

Provided that $|\phi|<1$, an $AR(1)$ process has the linear representation $$X_t = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi^k \epsilon_{t-k}$$
with respect to the iid noise $(\epsilon_t)$. It follows from the theorem cited above that $X_t$ is strongly stationary and thus all the margins have the same characteristic function.

Comment: Hello @JoseAvilez!! Would it be true that if we had a known starting value $X_0$, then the CF would be $E[e^{bX_n}]=e^{b\alpha^n X_0}\prod_{k\leq n}E[e^{b\alpha^{n-k}\varepsilon_k}]$ which would then depend on the index $n$?

Comment: Hey @Snoop! Yes, that is correct. Notice, however, that the OP indexed their time series by $\mathbb{Z}$, which is the more common situation, in which case you do have a strongly stationary process.

Comment: ah yes, I didn't notice!! OP's case is indeed the general one